# What if I choose us-central1-a zone for my google compute VM Instance and my traffic, calling VM is from asia? (in respect of pricing & efficiency)

Tags: performance, google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, google-compute-engine

I am trying to create a Google Compute VM Instance which will host my website, the traffic to this website will be coming mostly from asia, so which region should I select for my compute VM Instance.
How selecting of region will effect on the pricing and performance?

Comment: StackOverflow is a programming Q&A site. As this question is not about programming, it is off-topic here.   Perhaps [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/) can help you with the performance question. The pricing question will be off-topic on all of StackExchange, I'm afraid. That's a question for Google support.

Comment: Please do not close this question. The answer is good and may prevent similar questions from appearing in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [Best practices for Compute Engine regions selection](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/best-practices-compute-engine-region-selection) section [Factors to consider when selecting regions](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/best-practices-compute-engine-region-selection#factors_to_consider_when_selecting_regions):

> **Latency**
>
> **The main factor to consider is the latency your user experiences**.
>   However, this is a complex problem because user latency is affected by
>   multiple aspects, such as caching and load-balancing mechanisms.
>
> In enterprise use cases, latency to on-premises systems or latency for
>   a certain subset of users or partners is more critical. For example,
>   choosing the closest region to your developers or on-premises database
>   services interconnected with Google Cloud might be the deciding
>   factor.

For example you can serf some sites located and Asia and then compare your experience to sites located in US - you'll notice significant difference in response caused by latency. The same with your site - it'll be less responsive. You should set up your VM instance as close to your customers as possible.

To estimate pricing check resources below:

> **Pricing**
>
> Google Cloud resource costs differ by region. The following resources
>   are available to estimate the price:
>
> - [Compute Engine pricing](https://cloud.google.com/skus/?currency=USD)
> - [Pricing calculator](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator)
> - [Google Cloud SKUs](https://cloud.google.com/skus)
> - [Billing API](https://cloud.google.com/billing/reference/rest/v1/services.skus/list)
>
> If you decide to deploy in multiple regions, be aware that there are
>   [network egress charges](https://cloud.google.com/compute/network-pricing#general) for data synced between regions.

In addition, you can find monthly estimate cost in `Create a new instance wizard` as well - try to set different regions and you'll get the numbers.

If your customers located in different regions you can try [Google Cloud CDN](https://cloud.google.com/cdn/docs):

> Cloud CDN (Content Delivery Network) uses Google's globally
>   distributed edge points of presence to cache HTTP(S) load balanced
>   content close to your users. Caching content at the edges of Google's
>   network provides faster delivery of content to your users while
>   reducing serving costs.